# Simpler way to count the number of duplicated rows in a text file

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, text-files, duplicates

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
abc
bcd
abc
efg
bcd
abc
```

And the expected output is this:

```
3 abc 
2 bcd
1 efg
```

I know there is an existed solution for this:

```
sort -k2 < inFile |
awk '!z[$1]++{a[$1]=$0;} END {for (i in a) print z[i], a[i]}' |
sort -rn -k1 > outFile
```

The code sorts, removes duplicates, and sorts again, and prints the expected output. 
However, is there a simpler way to express the z[$1]++{a[$1]=$0} part? More "basic", I mean.

Comment: why is the expected output have `2 abc` when there are 3 occurrences of `abc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More basic:

```
$ sort inFile | uniq -c
      3 abc
      2 bcd
      1 efg
```

#### More basic awk

When one is used to awk's idioms, the expression `!z[$1]++{a[$1]=$0;}` is clear and concise.  For those used to programming in other languages, other forms might be more familiar, such as:

```
awk '{if (z[$1]++ == 0) a[$1]=$0;} END {for (i in a) print z[i], a[i]}'
```

Or,

```
awk '{if (z[$1] == 0) a[$1]=$0; z[$1]+=1} END {for (i in a) print z[i], a[i]}'
```

Comment: not his expected output, although this is exactly what i was thinking.

Comment: @ptierno Yes.  Since the OP's awk statement produces a count of 3 for `abc`, I assumed that the 2 was a typo.

Comment: Ah yes I made a typo there. It should have been 3 abc.

Answer (score 0):

If your input file contains billions of lines and you want to avoid sort, then you can just do:

```
awk '{a[$0]++} END{for(x in a) print a[x],x}' file.txt
```